# A bank account with that routing number and account number already exists for this customer Plaid+Stripe Exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, stripe-payments, plaid

I have Implement Plaid+Stripe in my Xamarin.Forms application. I have one bank account added and when trying to link another bank account I'm getting 400 bad request from stripe with this message:

> A bank account with that routing number and account number already
> exists for this customer

**Api I have used: https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/CustomerId/sources**

Anyone know how to fix this error, and is it possible to link Multiple bank accounts in stripe payment using same UserID? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That means the customer you're trying to update already has that specific bank account attached to them. Make sure that the new bank account has a different account and routing number from the previously attached one.